# Mapping string to UUID in go

Tags: go

I'm using [mitchellh/mapstructure](https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure) to map from `map[string]interface{}` to `struct`

Is there any way to tell `mapstructure` to convert `string` to `uuid.UUID`?

###### `map[string]interface{}`:

```json
{
    "id": "af7926b1-98eb-4c96-a2ba-7e429085b2ad",
    "title": "new title",
}
```

###### `struct`

```golang
package entities

import (
    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

type Post struct {
    Id      uuid.UUID  `json:"id"`
    Title   string     `json:"title"`
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a `DecodeHookFunc`:

```
func decode(input, output interface{}) error {
    config := &mapstructure.DecoderConfig{
        DecodeHook: mapstructure.ComposeDecodeHookFunc(
            stringToUUIDHookFunc(),
        ),
        Result: &output,
    }

    decoder, err := mapstructure.NewDecoder(config)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return decoder.Decode(input)
}

func stringToUUIDHookFunc() mapstructure.DecodeHookFunc {
    return func(f reflect.Type, t reflect.Type, data interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
        if f.Kind() != reflect.String {
            return data, nil
        }
        if t != reflect.TypeOf(uuid.UUID{}) {
            return data, nil
        }

        return uuid.Parse(data.(string))
    }
}
```

- Source: https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure/issues/236
- Documentation:
  https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure#DecodeHookFunc

Comment: Thanks, your code works like a charm!